# Unable to mock public methods of another class using powermockito

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I am writing junit for a class using PowerMockito. I am able to mock private methods but unable to mock public methods of another class. Below in the test class , the object of B is not getting mocked.
What am i doing wrong here?

```
 class A {
  
  B b = new B();
  
  public String handleData() {
    String parameter = getParameter();
    String data = b.getData();
    .....
 }
  
  private String getParameter(){
    .......
    .....
  }
}
```

Another class B with all public methods

```
class B {
  public String getData() {
  .......
  .....
  }
}
```

Now i have the test class for class A

```
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(fullyQualifiedNames = "org.example.A")
class TestA {
  @Mock
  B b;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void handleDataTest()

   A a = spy(new A());
   doReturn("test").when(a, "getParameter");
   >>>>>  when(b.getData().thenReturn("test);
   .........
   .....
   AssertNotNull(a.handleData());
}
```

Below are the dependencies i am using -

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-beta.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-beta.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.13.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: "*`when(b.getData().thenReturn("test);`*" - This will not compile. --- I would highly suggest to not use powermock when possible since powermock uses bytecode manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

`B b = new B();` creates new instance of B inside object A, whenever an object of A is created. The instance of B can be mocked only if the B is injected somehow into object A.

Comment: "*The instance of B can be mocked only if the B is injected somehow into object A.*" - This is not true, if powermock is used. We can mock constructors with powermock.